# MySQL: Returning first occurrence or record by date

Tags: mysql

I'm trying return the first occurrence of an ID, by primary key and date (from timestamp column). Here is an example of how the data would look:
[image]

In this example, the following ID's should be returned:
111, 333, 444

Note: I want to de-dupe by email / date (returning id from min timestamp). 333 and 444 are returned, because while tied to same email, they have different date. 222 isn't returned, because tied to same email / date as 111, where 111 has earlier timestamp

Comment: Why wouldn't you return 222 ?

Comment: I want to de-dupe by email / date (returning id from min timestamp). 333 and 444 are returned, because while tied to same email, they have different date. 222 isn't returned, because tied to same email / date as 111, where 111 has earlier timestamp.

Comment: . . That is a tremendous clarification and should really be added into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you can do this by getting the minimum timestamp for each email/date combination.  Then you can join back to get additional information from the row:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select email, min(timestamp) as mints
      from table t
      group by email, date(timestamp)
     ) tt
     on t.email = tt.email and t.timestamp = tt.mints;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create table your_table(id int, email varchar(10), t timestamp)
;
insert into your_table values
(111,'a@a','2015-01-01 00:00:00'),
(222,'a@a','2015-01-01 10:00:00'),
(333,'b@b','2015-01-01 08:00:00'),
(444,'b@b','2015-02-01 09:00:00')

select substring_index(ids,',',1)
from (
    select email,
           date(t) as dt,
           group_concat(id order by t) as ids
    from your_table
    group by email,date(t)
    order by email,date(t)
    ) as tmp
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0c11/2)**